# how can you use awk's positional args in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I use the following snippet to kill abruptly any java process running:

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | awk "{print $2}" | xargs kill -9
```

I would like to have this in a shell script that I can run on multiple machines but when I put it in the script and run it it takes the $2 in the awk as a passed in argument. I tried single, double and triple backslashing the $ but nothing works.

Single escape results in:

```
can't read "2": no such variable
```

Double escape results in:

```
awk: cmd. line:1 {print
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Triple escape results in:

```
awk: cmd. line:1 {print
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

So I'm looking for a way to pass the $ arguments awk uses into a shell script

Comment: You need to change the double quotes to single quotes in the `awk` expression. otherwise the `$2` is treated as a shell variable rather than a field/column in awk.

Comment: That said, `pgrep` or `pidof` is better suited for this imo.

Comment: I believe that awk has it own use for ${NUMBER} variables. Maybe a better way is to save the $ arguments to other variables and use them in you awk command.

Comment: `Java` is that bad that it needs the  `-9` ?

Comment: single or double quotes didnt matter. I tried both. I am using the in a function that uses expect so the entire line is double quoted. Jetchisel's suggestion of using pgrep was the only solution that worked

Comment: `I am using the in a function that uses expect so the entire line is double quoted` - then include that information in your question and show that code in your example since it's extremely important.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$ ps -ef | awk '/[j]ava/{print $2}'
```

Sample output:

```
28510
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(taken inspiration from @James fine answer here).

```
ps -ef | awk '/[j]ava/{cmd=(cmd?cmd OFS:"")$2} END{print "kill -9 " cmd}'
```

This will only print the kill command and once you are happy with its results(pid numbers etc) then run following command to actually kill pids.

```
ps -ef | awk '/[j]ava/{cmd=(cmd?cmd OFS:"")$2} END{print "kill -9 " cmd}' | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a command that does this:

```sh
pkill java
```

`pkill` accepts the `-signal` (e.g. `-9`) notation just like `kill`, but I recommend starting with weaker signals to afford time for the killed processes to shut down properly. I usually do `-HUP` (hangup, `-1`) then standard (no flag for terminate, `-TERM` or `-15`) then `-9` (kill, `-KILL`).

If you want to know what that'll do before running it, you can list the matching process IDs with:

```sh
pgrep java
```

or for more details:

```sh
pgrep -a java
```

(or `pgrep java |xargs ps -f` if you prefer)